# when i install the c# in Visual Studio Code,It's give me error

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
OmniSharp server started.
    Path: C:\Users\tlx_a\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.0\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 13212

System.NullReferenceException: 未将对象引用设置到对象的实例。
   在 OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder.SafeGetTypes(Assembly a) 位置 D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\CompositionHostBuilder.cs:行号 103
   在 System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   在 System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   在 System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   在 OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder.Build() 位置 D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\CompositionHostBuilder.cs:行号 88
   在 OmniSharp.Stdio.Host..ctor(TextReader input, ISharedTextWriter writer, IOmniSharpEnvironment environment, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CompositionHostBuilder compositionHostBuilder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) 位置 D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio\Host.cs:行号 47
   在 OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__1() 位置 D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver\Program.cs:行号 56
   在 OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start(Func`1 action) 位置 D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\HostHelpers.cs:行号 29
[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

The error like this.
I tried to install several versions, but nothing improved.